# The right way to convert from bazaar to git and sync them

Tags: git, bazaar, git-fast-import

I have a development repository in bazaar and I want to convert it to git and keep it synced. I need this because I will be sharing my code with someone who doesn't know bazaar.

first I needed to convert my bazaar repo to git. I googled around and I found [this](http://astrofloyd.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/convert-bzr-to-git/) blog which mentions simple steps to convert from bazaar to git. But when I tried to run `bzr fast-export` it says there is no such command.

I tried installing bzr fast-export, by `sudo apt-get install bzr-fastexport`. Seems I actually have to install fastimport. so I tried this : `sudo apt-get install bzr-fastimport`. Now I can also run bzr fastexport. And following command did successfully :

```
bzr fast-export | git fast-import
```

now I have the same repo in git. But how do I maintain sync? after googling up I found out that I have to use [git-bzr-ng](https://github.com/termie/git-bzr-ng), but there are no instructions on the github repo. Any idea how? or any other alternative?

Comment: the "bzr fast-import" and "bzr fast-export" commands are provided by the bzr-fastimport plugin; it lives at http://launchpad.net/bzr-fastimport

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple way to achieve this. bzr dpush does exactly what I want. However, `bzr-git` needs to be installed:

```
apt-get install bzr-git
```

Then all I had to run this:

```
bzr dpush https://bitbucket.org/myusername/myreponame,branch=master
```

It also supports `--directory` (or `-d`) argument if I want to run it from different directory. The command would be

```
bzr dpush -d /path/to/branch https://bitbucket.org/myusername/myreponame,branch=master
```

Comment: Pushing (and pulling) the BZR repo to GIT is I think the easier solution !

Comment: I found that `bzr-git` doesn't exist for Ubuntu Xenial, so use Trusty (14.04). If pushing to github, be sure to include the .git extension, e.g. `https://github.com/myusername/myreponame.git,branch=master`.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and simple way for exporting a bazaar project to git project has been described in  https://flexion.org/posts/2012-10-migrating-bzr-to-git .