# Converting bazaar repo to git on linux

Tags: git, github, bazaar

How can I convert bazaar repo to git? I have old zip archive with .bzr directory in it.

I've try to follow [this tutorial](https://flexion.org/posts/2012-10-migrating-bzr-to-git/) but when I try to install:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr-fastimport
```

it got error that there are no bzr-fastimport package and there is python-fastimport I've install it but

```
bzr fast-export --plain `pwd`
```

show error:

```
bzr: ERROR: unknown command "fast-export"
```

I've also try to follow the solution in answer to this question: [The right way to convert from bazaar to git and sync them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013206/the-right-way-to-convert-from-bazaar-to-git-and-sync-them)

I've created new repo on github but when I called:

```
bzr dpush https://github.com/jcubic/aikiframework.git,branch=master
```

I've got error:

```
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "https://github.com/jcubic/aikiframework.git,branch=trunk/".
```

Comment: The tutorial is for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS which is still available for download.  You could install it in a virtual machine just to do the conversion.

Comment: I can confirm that although the tutorial was for 10.04, the `sudo apt-get install bzr-fastimport` command still worked in 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no package for bzr-fastimport in version 16.04 I downloaded file bzr-fastimport_0.13.0.orig.tar.gz from [Yakkety Yak](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bzr-fastimport/0.13.0-4ubuntu1) unpack and copy to `~/.bazaar/plugins/fastimport` directory then I can call:

```
bzr fast-export --plain `pwd` | git fast-import
git remote add origin https://github.com/jcubic/aikiframework.git
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way to get the fastimport plugin for Bazaar (instead of downloading the Yakkety Yak package as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38933330/881084)) is to get it directly from its upstream source on Launchpad (thanks to [this blog post by Robin Winslow](https://design.canonical.com/2015/01/converting-projects-between-git-and-bazaar/)):

```
cd ~/.bazaar/plugins
bzr branch lp:bzr-fastimport fastimport
```

Then you can go back to the directory containing your bzr repo and do the conversion:

```
git init 
bzr fast-export --plain . | git fast-import
```

Comment: Note: you also need to `apt-get install python-fastimport`

Answer (score 2):

As an update. Since 18.04 (bionic), `bzr-fastimport` is again [part of Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bzr-fastimport&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and it seems that since 19.10 (eoan) it's even integrated in the package bzr.

The current conversion recipe would be to do install bzr and bzr-fastimport.

```
sudo apt install bzr
sudo apt install bzr-fastimport
```

and then in the Bazaar repository directory create a new Git repository, do the fast-export/import, checkout master on Git (should say "already on master") and then a new ".git" directory is created and the ".bzr" directory can be removed if necessary.

```
cd repo-dir
git init
bzr fast-export | git fast-import
git checkout -f master
rm -rf .bzr
```